# How to connect two nets

Tags: networking, server

There is an ordinary net config: router with internet 192.168.2.1, and client computers.

One of them - Ubuntu gateway server with DHCP (192.168.3.0), 1 netcard and 2 IP addresses (192.168.2.6, 192.168.3.10).

It has ping to everything, but the other PC (192.168.3.147), can ping 192.168.3.10 or 192.168.2.6, but can't ping 192.168.2.1, or any site.

How can I set this up?

**netplan:**

```
ethernets:
      eth0:
         addressess: [192.168.2.6/24, 192.168.3.10/24]
                  routes:
                        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                          via: 192.168.2.1
                          metric: 100
                        - to: 192.168.3.0/24
                          via: 192.168.3.10
                          metric: 100
                  nameservers:
                          addresses: [192.168.2.1, 8.8.8.8]
```

Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

A Gateway at least needs 2 net devices, one for wan and one for local net.

If wan is 192.168.2.0/24 then lan is 192.168.3.0/24
There should be eth0 for wan and eth1 for lan

Then you can setup your gateway to forward packets from wan to lan and vice versa.

Comment: But, maybe can I create some virtual intarface for lan? bound or something like?

Comment: But what use should that have? Then why not connect all your clients to wan?